# Python selenium cannot interact with element

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Selenium webdriver and cannot interact with an element after login. That means the element interactions works fine during the login screen.

The webdriver is HTMLUNITS. I don't want to use another headless driver because need to run this script on Windows and it's the only one that allows me to pass through the login screen. Already tried with PhantomJS (didn't work), and tried to configure headless_chrome without success.

The source code is here:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6edf78d63d698340b1ae53a597776037

The `<input>` that Im trying to interact is on line 209 from source code. Same than this:

```
<input id="ToolbarOkCode" ct="I" lsdata="{0:'ToolbarOkCode',1:'Command',4:200,13:'150px',23:true}" lsevents="{Change:[{ClientAction:'none'},{type:'TOOLBARINPUTFIELD'}],Enter:[{ClientAction:'submit',PrepareScript:'return\x20its.XControlSubmit\x28\x29\x3b',ResponseData:'delta',TransportMethod:'partial'},{Submit:'X',type:'TOOLBARINPUTFIELD'}]}" type="text" maxlength="200" tabindex="0" ti="0" title="Command" class="urEdf2TxtRadius urEdf2TxtEnbl urEdfVAlign" value="SM37" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" name="ToolbarOkCode" style="width:150px;"/>
```

I need to write a value and press ENTER to submit the `form`. There is not any "submit" `button`.

**1.** Tried this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ToolbarOkCode').send_keys('value')
driver.find_element_by_id('ToolbarOkCode').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Did not work. The element was found but the "send_keys" action does not work.

**2.** Tried using Javascript to fill the input field, works fine:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('ToolbarOkCode').setAttribute('value', 'SM37')")
```

**3.** Then tried to press ENTER, same error as before:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ToolbarOkCode').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

**4.** Tried to send a `submit()` event, apparently works but the form is not submitted at all:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('ToolbarOkCode').submit()
```

**TEST**

Tried also with this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='ToolbarOkCode']").send_keys("SM37")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='ToolbarOkCode']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Received same error as before:

```
12:12:11.233 INFO - Executing: [find element: By.xpath: //input[@id='ToolbarOkCode']])
12:12:11.432 INFO - Done: [find element: By.xpath: //input[@id='ToolbarOkCode']]
12:12:11.444 INFO - Executing: [send keys: 5 <input id="ToolbarOkCode" ct="I" lsdata="{0:'ToolbarOkCode',1:'Command',4:200,13:'150px',23:true}" lsevents="{Change:[{ClientAction:'none'},{type:'TOOLBARINPUTFIELD'}],Enter:[{ClientAction:'submit',PrepareScript:'return\x20its.XControlSubmit\x28\x29\x3b',ResponseData:'delta',TransportMethod:'partial'},{Submit:'X',type:'TOOLBARINPUTFIELD'}]}" type="text" maxlength="200" tabindex="0" ti="0" title="Command" class="urEdf2TxtRadius urEdf2TxtEnbl urEdfVAlign" value="" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" name="ToolbarOkCode" style="width:150px;" />, [S, M, 3, 7]])
12:12:12.718 WARN - Exception thrown======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[1] column=[0] lineSource=[  function (oDomEvent) {] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[http://sapmig03.cge.cl:8010/sap/public/icmandir/its/ls/js/lightspeed.js?600#3(eval)] message=[TypeError: Cannot call method "setOpenerRef" of null (http://sapmig03.cge.cl:8010/sap/public/icmandir/its/ls/js/lightspeed.js?600#3(eval)#1)]com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot call method "setOpenerRef" of null (http://sapmig03.cge.cl:8010/sap/public/icmandir/its/ls/js/lightspeed.js?600#3(eval)#1)
```

Any idea?

THanks in advance!

Comment: and are you able to do it manually ?

Comment: Yes, it works manually.

Comment: Looks like the same problem I'm having trying to automate an SAP webgui (I'm not using selenium; but this confirms that it wouldn't help). I'm pretty sure lightspeed.js is the key to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A small tweak to use an unique `xpath` instead of `id` may sort out the issue as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='ToolbarOkCode']").send_keys("value")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='ToolbarOkCode']").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

On a second thought it seems `submit()` may work better as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='ToolbarOkCode']").send_keys("value")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='ToolbarOkCode']").submit()
```

Keep me updated what works for you.

Comment: @DenisSoto The node you shared in the question, already contains an attribute as `value="SM37"` but we are again trying to `send_keys("SM37")`, are we missing here something?

Comment: Sorry. I have extracted the source code after my scripts was executed. That's why the `input` has the attribute `value="SM37"`. Before running the `value=""`

Comment: Can you update the question with the fresh `HTML` please for further analysis or else share the `url` if it is public?

Comment: @DenisSoto The HTML still contains `value="SM37"` which indicates it's not fresh.

Comment: DebanjanB, the URL was already updated. I don't know why you are seeing the old HTML, check this out: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6edf78d63d698340b1ae53a597776037